# Traversing unordered list using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, nested-lists

I have an unordered nested list

I want to count these nested lists in such a way that inside `<li>Animals</li>` there are 19 animals inside this **li**. I wanted to count all **li** having the name of animals using **Javascript**. How should I proceed?

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    Animals
    <ul>
      <li>
        Mammals
        <ul>
          <li>Apes
            <ul>
              <li>Chimpanzee</li>
              <li>Gorilla</li>
              <li>Orangutan</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Coyotes</li>
          <li>Dogs</li>
          <li>Elephants</li>
          <li>Horses</li>
          <li>Whales</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        Other
        <ul>
          <li>
            Birds
            <ul>
              <li>Albatross</li>
              <li>Emu</li>
              <li>Ostrich</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Lizards</li>
          <li>Snakes</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Fish
    <ul>
      <li>Goldfish</li>
      <li>Salmon</li>
      <li>Trout</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Something like `document.querySelectorAll("ul li:first-of-type li").length`, which gives 17.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("ul")[1].querySelectorAll("li").length` also give 17

Comment: What counts as "animal"? I count 16 (i.e. li with no ul child).

Comment: It could be that there are 14 actual animals, or fewer,  listed here. There may be some confusion between what is meant by Animal and what is meant by for example Species or groups of animals for example is Dogs an Animal, or is it a heading for potentially different types of dog. Could you clarify this further?

Comment: @AHaworth like inside **Apes** **li** there are 3 li's and inside **Mammals** there are 9 li's and inside **Others** there are 6 li's. So In a total of **Mammals** and **Other**, there will be 17 Li's inside **animals**. Which I have to count.

Comment: @RobG I have to count the number of **Li's** inside **Animals** **Li** which are 17 in total.

Comment: OK, got it, thanks for clarification. You want to count the total number of LI elements within the Animals element, nothing to do with whether they are animals or not - I got carried away by the semantics.

Comment: @AHaworth any idea how to count the number of **Li's** in each heading. Like 3 **li's** in Apes, 9 **Li's** in **Mammals** and 6 **Li's** in **Others**. 3 **Li's** inside **Fish**.

Comment: See my basic answer which counts the lis associated with the Animals li. This should lead you to see how to count the lis in different unordered lists. We can't do all the coding for you on SO I'm afraid, but I hope the answer gives you enough to get started.

Comment: You need to find the *Animals* li and count the descendant lis, .e.g. `document.querySelectorAll('li:first-of-type li').length`.

Answer (score 0):

@mplungjan put forward this solution in the comments and it works. `document.querySelectorAll("ul")[1].querySelectorAll("li").length`

this gives 17 which is the correct count (after clarification in comments which overrode the first count given which was 19).

The question asks about **traversing** and we show that step by step here so as to help with more general solutions.

We first have to find the element which is holding all the other lists. I have assumed that that ul element is the first in the document. In the general case we'd probably find such an element by knowing it's id or its class.

We then find the li element which is associated with Animals and again we assume it's the first one, as it is in the HTML given. However, if it was to be more sophisticated you'd want to look for the li element that has Animals as its innerHTML.

We then find the associated lis and count them.

Here is the code and you can run the snippet to see it gets to 17 (which was clarified in comments, the original count in the question was given as 19, also clarified was that this has nothing to do with counting actual animal names, only to do with counting li elements).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<ul>
  <li>
    Animals
    <ul>
      <li>
        Mammals
        <ul>
          <li>Apes
            <ul>
              <li>Chimpanzee</li>
              <li>Gorilla</li>
              <li>Orangutan</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Coyotes</li>
          <li>Dogs</li>
          <li>Elephants</li>
          <li>Horses</li>
          <li>Whales</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        Other
        <ul>
          <li>
            Birds
            <ul>
              <li>Albatross</li>
              <li>Emu</li>
              <li>Ostrich</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Lizards</li>
          <li>Snakes</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Fish
    <ul>
      <li>Goldfish</li>
      <li>Salmon</li>
      <li>Trout</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<script>

var firstUL = document.getElementsByTagName('UL')[0]; //assuming the whole list is the first UL in the document
var animalsLI = firstUL.getElementsByTagName('LI')[0];
var animalsLIUL = animalsLI.getElementsByTagName('UL')[0];
var animalsLIs = animalsLI.getElementsByTagName('LI');

alert('The count of LIs is ' + animalsLIs.length);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("ul")[1].querySelectorAll("li").length;` this works for me.

Comment: But here is a problem. `var textUl = document.querySelector("ul").getElementsByTagName('li');`    `textUl[0].textContent = 'Animals(' + firstUl + ')';` this thing shrink all the **Animla** li's and show the text.

Comment: @mplungjan said document.querySelectorAll("ul")[1].querySelectorAll("li").length gives 17 and that answer is absolutely correct but my answer wanted to show traversing step by step as traversing was given in the title and to help with anyone seeking a more general solution.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to do with assigning'Animals(' + firstUl + ')'; to textUl[0].textContent. Are you tryng to overwrite the innerHTML, ie actually remove some stuff from the DOM, ?  and it has an error - what is firstUl? It has not been defined anywhere (though perhaps you have renamed my variables?) Try running the code with your browser's dev tools and look at the console this should help with getting syntax etc error removed. It may be that what you are asking now was not in the original question? Sorry I am confused so not helpful at the moment.